# Change Query to View

Tags: mysql, join

I have a working query below that I would like to turn into a view however I am getting the error "View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause.

Can someone assist in rewriting it in a way that would allow me to create a view with it please? The query is also a bit slow so I am hoping that rewriting it may speed it up as well. Thanks for your help.

**QUERY**

```
SELECT
    client_ig_client_list.Account_ID,
    client_ig_client_list.`Name`,
    Total_Deposits,
    Total_Withdrawals,
    Withdrawals_And_Deposits,
    Current_Balance,
    Share_Status,
    Forex_Status,
    Index_Status,
    Share_Weighting,
    Forex_Weighting,
    Index_Weighting
FROM
    client_ledger_history
LEFT JOIN client_ig_client_list ON client_ig_client_list.Account_ID = client_ledger_history.Account_ID
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        Account_ID,
        SUM(Profit_Loss) AS Total_Deposits
    FROM
        client_ledger_history
    WHERE
        Summary = 'Cash In'
    GROUP BY
        Account_ID WITH ROLLUP
) AS client_ledger_aggregated_history ON client_ledger_aggregated_history.Account_ID = client_ledger_history.Account_ID
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        Account_ID,
        SUM(Profit_Loss) AS Total_Withdrawals
    FROM
        client_ledger_history
    WHERE
        Summary = 'Cash Out'
    GROUP BY
        Account_ID WITH ROLLUP
) AS client_ledger_aggregated1_history ON client_ledger_aggregated1_history.Account_ID = client_ledger_history.Account_ID
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        Account_ID,
        SUM(Profit_Loss) AS Withdrawals_And_Deposits
    FROM
        client_ledger_history
    WHERE
        Summary = 'Cash Out'
    OR Summary = 'Cash In'
    GROUP BY
        Account_ID WITH ROLLUP
) AS client_ledger_aggregated2_history ON client_ledger_aggregated2_history.Account_ID = client_ledger_history.Account_ID
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        Account_ID,
        SUM(Profit_Loss) AS Current_Balance
    FROM
        client_ledger_history
    GROUP BY
        Account_ID WITH ROLLUP
) AS client_ledger_aggregated3_history ON client_ledger_aggregated3_history.Account_ID = client_ledger_history.Account_ID
GROUP BY
    Account_ID
```

Comment: Do you have correct indexes setup on the columns which you filter rows by the most? I would look at that before creating a view. They aren't always quicker, even when your query is as complex as this.  How many rows does the query deal with? / schema have?

Comment: Hi @Adam , yes they are all indexed and it deals with about 700,000 rows and growing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned and referenced you cannot create a view with a subquery in the from clause. The solution is to create 4 views based on your 4 subqueries, and then either just run your resultant query on its own, or create a view with that. and see if that improves anything.

Your first view would be named `client_ledger_aggregated_history`
created from the query

```
SELECT
        Account_ID,
        SUM(Profit_Loss) AS Total_Deposits
    FROM
        client_ledger_history
    WHERE
        Summary = 'Cash In'
    GROUP BY
        Account_ID WITH ROLLUP
```

second view named `client_ledger_aggregated1_history`
created from the query

```
SELECT
        Account_ID,
        SUM(Profit_Loss) AS Total_Withdrawals
    FROM
        client_ledger_history
    WHERE
        Summary = 'Cash Out'
    GROUP BY
        Account_ID WITH ROLLUP
```

3rd view named `client_ledger_aggregated2_history`
created from the query

```
    SELECT
            Account_ID,
            SUM(Profit_Loss) AS Withdrawals_And_Deposits
        FROM
            client_ledger_history
        WHERE
            Summary = 'Cash Out'
        OR Summary = 'Cash In'
        GROUP BY
            Account_ID WITH ROLLUP
```

and 4th view named `client_ledger_aggregated3_history`
created from the query

```
SELECT
        Account_ID,
        SUM(Profit_Loss) AS Current_Balance
    FROM
        client_ledger_history
    GROUP BY
        Account_ID WITH ROLLUP
```

And finally you could test the following query on its own, or create a view from that.

```
SELECT
    client_ig_client_list.Account_ID,
    client_ig_client_list.`Name`,
    Total_Deposits,
    Total_Withdrawals,
    Withdrawals_And_Deposits,
    Current_Balance,
    Share_Status,
    Forex_Status,
    Index_Status,
    Share_Weighting,
    Forex_Weighting,
    Index_Weighting
FROM
    client_ledger_history
LEFT JOIN client_ig_client_list ON client_ig_client_list.Account_ID = client_ledger_history.Account_ID
LEFT JOIN client_ledger_aggregated_history ON client_ledger_aggregated_history.Account_ID = client_ledger_history.Account_ID
LEFT JOIN client_ledger_aggregated1_history ON client_ledger_aggregated1_history.Account_ID = client_ledger_history.Account_ID
LEFT JOIN client_ledger_aggregated2_history ON client_ledger_aggregated2_history.Account_ID = client_ledger_history.Account_ID
LEFT JOIN client_ledger_aggregated3_history ON client_ledger_aggregated3_history.Account_ID = client_ledger_history.Account_ID
GROUP BY
    Account_ID
```

A final note given that the reason for creating a view is because of speed issues, and you mention that the amount of rows in your database is growing, you should consider the sizes of your indexes (which you can find the individual values of using [This think](http://aadant.com/blog/2014/02/04/how-to-calculate-a-specific-innodb-index-size/)). And how they compare to the available memory on your server.

Comment: Thanks @Adam for such a detailed response. I will do that.

Comment: no worries, got alot from this site so like to give back what I can ;)

Answer (score 2):

The SELECT statement cannot contain a subquery in the FROM clause.
Your workaround would be to create a view for each of your subqueries. And then use appropriate joins for all the views

[Reference Document](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html)